# Tensile strength of collagen?

Tags: proteins, human-anatomy, data, bio-mechanics

Really specific question, but what is the average tensile strength of human collagen, type I? I've tried looking for it online, and either my google-fu skills are weak, or I'm just unlucky. Also, is there a specific database for mechanical protien data, or do I just have to look up each protien's tensile strength individually?

Comment: Measuring mechanical properties of proteins is REALLY hard, because you either need to measure individual proteins (which is afaik only possible with an atomic force microscope) or you need to assemble purified protein into a larger complex that is normally measureable, however single purified proteins often don't from physiological complexes.

Comment: @Nicolai, I'm specifically interested in scleroprotiens, but i don't know if that helps?